# how to calculate from file and print result to another file in File I/O java

Tags: java, file, io

i have this assignment :
File input scores.txt contains matric number and marks for six quizzes. Maximum mark for each quiz is 15. Write a program that reads matric number and marks from the input file. Calculate total and average for each student and write into output file. Scores are separated by blanks. Using the calculated average mark, convert it to percentage and set a grade based on UTM grading scheme.

[image: image of tables of inputs and outputs]

i do this coding but i have problem when i press run there is errors

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.*;
public class Q1 {
public static int number,number1,number2;
public static double sum,sum1,sum2,average,average1,average2;

public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    java.io.File file=new java.io.File("input.txt");
    Scanner input=new Scanner(file);
    while(input.hasNext()){

        number=input.nextInt();
        int q1=input.nextInt();
        int q2=input.nextInt();
        int q3=input.nextInt();
        int q4=input.nextInt();
        int q5=input.nextInt();
        sum=q1+q2+q3+q4+q5;
        average=sum/5;
        number1=input.nextInt();
        int q21=input.nextInt();
        int q22=input.nextInt();
        int q23=input.nextInt();
        int q24=input.nextInt();
        int q25=input.nextInt();
        sum1=q21+q22+q23+q24+q25;
        average1=sum/5;
        number2=input.nextInt();
        int q31=input.nextInt();
        int q32=input.nextInt();
        int q33=input.nextInt();
        int q34=input.nextInt();
        int q35=input.nextInt();
        sum2=q31+q32+q33+q34+q35;
        average2=sum/5;

        input.close();
    }
       PrintWriter output=new java.io.PrintWriter("file1.txt");
       output.print(number);
       output.print(sum);
       output.println(average);
       output.print(number1);
       output.print(sum1);
       output.println(average1);
       output.print(number2);
       output.print(sum2);
       output.println(average2);
       output.close();
       PrintWriter output1=new java.io.PrintWriter("file2.txt");
       output.print(number);
       output.print(sum);
       output.println(check(average));
       output.print(number1);
       output.print(sum1);
       output.println(check(average1));
       output.print(number2);
       output.print(sum2);
       output.println(check(average2));
       output.close();
}
public static double check(double a){

    if(a>=80){
        System.out.print("A");


    }
    else if((a<80)&&(a>=70)){
        System.out.print("B");

        }
    else if((a>=60)&&(a<70)){
        System.out.print("C");
    }
    else 
        System.out.print("D");
    return a;

}

}
```

Comment: What errors do you have?, please post them..

Comment: Put input.close outside of the loop. Otherwise, you close the scanner and then check for nextInt on it.

Answer (score 0):

You do have a typo regarding the output:

```
PrintWriter output1=new java.io.PrintWriter("file2.txt");
output.print(number);
output.print(sum);
output.println(check(average));
output.print(number1);
output.print(sum1);
output.println(check(average1));
output.print(number2);
output.print(sum2);
output.println(check(average2));
output.close();
```

You forgot to change it to `output1`.